# php strpos doing weird things

Tags: php, strpos

I have this code here and for some reason it will accept either the first 3 ifs as true or the last if.  I can't seem to get it to go to one or the other without just removing one of them.

The input coming in for example is 'TBN D664' or 'Other' and it will sort out down there. But no matter what input I throw at it 'TAN D664' is always true.

Even if I rearrange them they still say that whatever statement is first, is true.  I've used similar code elsewhere in my program and it works fine, only in this spot is it giving me troubles.

```
if($Category == 'Petrochemical') {

    if (strpos($_SESSION['Petrochemical_app'],'TAN D664') !== false) {
        $i=37;
    } 

    elseif (strpos($_SESSION['Petrochemical_app'],'TBN D2869') !== false) {
        $i=37;
    }

    elseif (strpos($_SESSION['Petrochemical_app'],'TBN D4739') !== false) {
        $i=37;
    }

    elseif ((strpos($_SESSION['Petrochemical_app'],'H2S') !== false) ||  
        (strpos($_SESSION['Petrochemical_app'],'Other') !== false)) {
        if( (strpos($sample,'75to120') !==false) || 
            (strpos($sample,'120to200') !==false) || 
            (strpos($sample,'200ormore') !==false)){
            $i=26;
        }
        if( (strpos($sample,'10to30') !== false) || 
            (strpos($sample,'less10') !== false)){
            $i=24;
        }
        if(strpos($sample,'30to75') !== false) {
            $i=25;
        }
    }
}
```

If it helps this is the checkbox where it gets this specific selection.

```
<fieldset>
  <b>Petrochemical</b><br />
  <input onclick="document.getElementById('selector_button').disabled = false; document.getElementById('charstype').disabled = true;"name="Petrochemical_app[]" type="checkbox" value="TAN D664" id="D664"> <label for="D664">TAN: D664</label>
  <input onclick="document.getElementById('selector_button').disabled = false; document.getElementById('charstype').disabled = true;"name="Petrochemical_app[]" type="checkbox" value="TBN D2869" id="D2869"> <label for="D2869">TBN: D2869</label>
  <input onclick="document.getElementById('selector_button').disabled = false; document.getElementById('charstype').disabled = true;"name="Petrochemical_app[]" type="checkbox" value="TBN D4739" id="D4739"> <label for="D4739">TBN: D4739</label>
  <input onclick="document.getElementById('selector_button').disabled = false; document.getElementById('charstype').disabled = true;"name="Petrochemical_app[]" type="checkbox" value="H2S and Mercaptan Bromine Number" id="H2S"> <label for="H2S">H2S and Mercaptan Bromine Number</label>
  <input onclick="document.getElementById('selector_button').disabled = false; document.getElementById('charstype').disabled = true;"name="Petrochemical_app[]" type="checkbox" value="Other" id="Other"> <label for="Other">Other: specify below</label>
  <label for="Other5">Please Specify:</label> <input name="Other5" type="text" id="Other5">
  </fieldset>
```

Here's where I turn it into a session

```
$_SESSION['Petrochemical_app']=$_POST['Petrochemical_app'];
```

Also when I do a print_r(); I get this or it changes whenever I make a different selection with the checkboxes

```
Array ( [0] => TBN D4739 )
```

Also if I have all of them checked off I get this

```
Array ( [0] => TAN D664 [1] => TBN D2869 [2] => TBN D4739 [3] => H2S and Mercaptan Bromine Number [4] => Other )
```

P.S. Thanks for helping with the code format guys!  I'm a long time stackoverflow creeper and this is my first post :P

Comment: What's the input, that is what's in `$_SESSION['Petrochemical_app']`?

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd are the same thing, aren't they?

Comment: you know, that you can use **elseif**? you know, that in php **switch()** exsists?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, they are identical.

Comment: Yeah the first 3 are supposed to have different things but no matter what the input is it shows the last     
if( (strpos($_SESSION['Petrochemical_app'],'H2S') !== false) ||  
        (strpos($_SESSION['Petrochemical_app'],'Other') !== false))    As true

Comment: @Paul The input is from a checkbox, and mo matter what I select either the first is true or the last one.   I just ended up repeating the first statement to see if it cares about the difference.

Comment: @user1623005 Um... this might be a silly question but I'll ask it anyway: `session_start();` is loaded, right?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, I do have session_start(); and I've got other statements that are working that are pretty much the same as this one.

Comment: @donald123 yeah, I've updated it to use elseif.  I'm not really sure how to use switch() in this case.

Comment: @dup3 Regardless where the input comes from, do a `var_dump()` or `print_r()` on that variable and show it to us. Otherwise, how could we possible check anything? You did add the HTML, are you aware that form data is probably send via `POST` but you are looking in `$_SESSION`? Additionally, are you aware that `$_POST['Petrochemical_app']` is an array and you are using string functions? Show us the snippet where you transfer data from post to session.

Comment: @Paul Thanks, I've updated my question to show what is in the array and show that the data is passing through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your updates the error is quite clear, I think.

```
if (strpos($_SESSION['Petrochemical_app'],'TAN D664') !== false) {
    $i=37;
}
```

should be

```
if (in_array('TAN D664', $_SESSION['Petrochemical_app'])) {
    $i=37;
}
```

Since the form has several checkboxes with the same name, the values are put into an array which you then save in the session. Your code used string functions on that array which obviously can't work. You want to check if a specific value is in the array and thus should use `in_array([needle], [haystack])` to check that.

Comment: Thanks so much! That's the ticket and it sucks because that's how I started with these if statements but I couldn't get it to work either. You're a hero sir.